# Ubuntu server MySQL remote access from MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

I have a newly install Ubuntu installed the MySQL server.

After the basic config:

- I changed the *my.cnf* file and commented out the `bind_address`
- I can start the server and added iptable for `3306`.
- I also added the privileges to MySQL server as follow:

  - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%'`
  - `IDENTIFIED BY 'P@ssw0rd' WITH GRANT OPTION;`
  - `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
  - `exit`

However, after I connected from the MySQL workbench, it shows no database. But it seems that have login.

Anyone have faced that or can help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515745/create-a-new-database-with-mysql-workbench

Comment: This question is about database administration and is off topic on Pro Webmasters.   It has been asked and answered on StackOverflow already.

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick search and found these two answers that may help. They seem complete to me where much of the other information I found was too fragmented and incomplete. I like the first link best.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15663001/remote-connections-mysql-ubuntu

[Update]

Here is a run-down:

Log-on using your favorite SSH terminal.

Edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (may be `/etc/my.cnf`) with your favorite editor (vi or pico are most popular).

Find the section marked as `[mysqld]`.

Add or modify the line: `bind-address=*YOUR-SERVER-IP*` where *YOUR-SERVER-IP* is your public IP address.

Restart MySql: `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

If your MySql user does not exist:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

... where myuser is your desired username and mypass your desired password...

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

... to grant privileges to the user.

If your user already exists, then just issue the GRANT statements.

I use MySql Workbench which can make this process point and click. You can find it here for free: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Let us know if this helps.